# Add static file to Resource folder with ionic in XCode project

Tags: android, ios, xcode, ionic-framework, localization

I need to add some files to the "**Resource**" folder of the **IONIC** *generated XCode project*.

File is **InfoPlist.strings**, in order to localizate the permission messages, this one:

[image]

I've added files in the ionic project folder:

"Resources/ios/localization/de.lproj/InfoPlist.strings"
"Resources/ios/localization/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings"
"Resources/ios/localization/es.lproj/InfoPlist.strings"
"Resources/ios/localization/it.lproj/InfoPlist.strings"
"Resources/ios/localization/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings"

[image]

### My question is:

- What is the way to copy these files when "`ionic build ios`" is executed, directly in the XCode resource folder?
- I need to add something particular in the `config.xml` file? If yes, what?

---

Extract of `config.xml` file:

```
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <config-file parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
      <false/>
    </config-file>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    [...]
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480" />
  </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by creating a new "empty" plugin.

In the `plugin.xml` file I've simply added:

```
<platform name="ios">
    [...]
    <resource-file src="PermissionLocalized.bundle/de.lproj" />
    <resource-file src="PermissionLocalized.bundle/en.lproj" />
    <resource-file src="PermissionLocalized.bundle/es.lproj" />
    <resource-file src="PermissionLocalized.bundle/it.lproj" />
    <resource-file src="PermissionLocalized.bundle/fr.lproj" />
</platform>
```

and this copy these files on the resource folder of XCode project.